# What are some best practices to cook salmon on a cedar plank in an oven?

Tags: oven, salmon, cedar-plank

I know that cedar plank cooking is normally done on a grill but I want to see what I can do with it indoors.

What are some ways to get more of the wood flavor when cooking salmon with a cedar plank in the oven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big key is just to soak the plank before using it, that way it won't burn while it's in the oven.  The amount of time needed to soak seems to differ among experts, but soaking for an hour should be long enough to cook the salmon without the wood burning.

Answer (score 6):

The experts at [Outdoor Gourmet](http://www.outdoorgourmet.com) [suggest](http://www.outdoorgourmet.com/how-to/cedar-plank-in-the-oven):

- Soak the grilling plank for 1-2 hrs.
- Preheat the oven to 350°-400°.
- Place food on grilling plank; place the grilling plank in oven. Put a baking dish under it to catch the drips.
- Bake according to recipe until done.
- Reserve grilling plank to use again in the oven or on the grill.

Comment: An edit from [craig](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/4960/craig) fixed the URL but added something better as a separate comment : One note about cooking on planks is that you don't need to flip your salmon. Place it skin side down and it will cook completely through.

Answer (score 2):

Also worth mentioning is to be careful about the wood you choose. If you want to be spendy and buy actual grilling planks that's fine, but if you try to be clever and cut down wood planks on your own then make sure you avoid pressure-treated lumber. It contains some rather nasty poisonous chemicals that will evaporate at oven and grill temperatures.